# Why does my Python while loop not terminate?

Tags: python, while-loop

I'm new to programming and I'm struggling with a python while loop in one of my projects.  I simplified what I'm doing to the code below.  The while loop below doesn't terminate when count1 or count2 reaches a value of 2.  What am I missing here?

```
count1 = 0
count2 = 0
while count1 < 2 or count2 < 2:
    print('count 1 : ' + str(count1) + ' count 2: ' + str(count2))

    q = int(input('enter 1 or 2'))

    if q == 1:
        count1 += 1
    if q == 2:
        count2 += 1
```

Comment: change `or` to `and`

Comment: Do you want it to terminate when *either* is greater than or equal to `2`? Because if so, you wanted `and`, not `or`.

Comment: `or` in while conditional statement means *if any is tree, please run block below*, so only  both count1 and count2 greate or equal to 2,  the loop will terminates.

Comment: I want it to terminate when either are greater than or equal to 2.  If count1 reaches 2, I would like for it to terminate.  But if count2 reaches a value of 2 first, I would also like for it to terminate.  I don't care which count# reaches two first, I just want it to terminate when either count# reaches 2.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you have used `or` condition on `while` loop.

`or` returns true when `count1` or `count2` is less than 2 and returns false when both `values >= 2`.

So on your code, the `while` loop will be terminated once `count1 >= 2` and `count2 >= 2`.

To terminate `while` loop when one of `count1` and `count2` reaches a value of `2`, you use `and` instead of `or` as follows.

```
while count1 < 2 and count2 < 2
  ...
```

Comment: OK great. I think that clears it up for me then. I was not thinking of the while loop in the correct way.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can check of the condition is true and then break

```
count1 = 0
count2 = 0
while True:
    print('count 1 : ' + str(count1) + ' count 2: ' + str(count2))
    q = int(input('enter 1 or 2'))
    if q == 1:
        count1 += 1
    if q == 2:
        count2 += 1
    if count1 > 2 or count2 > 2:
        break
```